# Define a command with arguments that have a behaviour if called without arguments

Tags: macros, brackets

It is possible to define a command like `\Sign` that would work the following way?

- `\Sign` do `\mathsf{Sign}`
- `\Sign{foo}` do `\mathsf{Sign}\left(foo\right)`

I specifically want this for functions: the argument of the macro being the argument of the function and the macro without bracket writing the name of the function (i.e, remove the left and write parenthesis).

**Edit:** I precise I would want to use braces, and not the `[]` of optional arguments.

Comment: you can do this, but the standard latex syntax would be to use `\Sign[foo]`

Comment: Yes, but I would specifically want to use bracket and not an optional argument.

Comment: note \left \right produces sub-optimal horizontal spacing and you are better to use `\Sign(foo)` unless foo is large enough to require stretching

Comment: I didn't know for the spacing problem. Thanks!

Comment: The TeX gurus in here are strictly against this kind of syntax, but my package `semantex` uses this kind of syntax by default (sorry for advertising).

Comment: Thanks for the indication! I will check this package : )

Answer (score 8):

It's possible, but heartily discouraged.

Why not a more natural syntax such as

```
\Sign
\Sign(a)
```

that can also accommodate an optional sizing argument?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Signop}{\mathsf{Sign}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{(}{)}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Sign}{sO{}d()}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {{\Signop}}% just the function name as ordinary symbol
    {\SignArg{#1}{#2}{#3}}% the more complex construction
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SignArg}{mmm}{%
  \Signop % the operator
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% extensible delimiter
    \parens*{#3}%
   }
   {% sized delimiter
    \parens[#2]{#3}%
   }
}

\begin{document}

Ordinary: $a+\Sign+x$

\bigskip

With argument: $a+\Sign(b)+x$

\bigskip

With argument and size: $a+\Sign[\Big](b)+x$

\bigskip

With extensible fences: $a+\Sign*(\dfrac{1}{2})+x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why avoiding unconditional `\left` and `\right`? Consider

```
$\Sign*(\hat{X})$ versus $\Sign(\hat{X})$ or $\Sign[\big](\hat{X})$
```

where the `*`-version uses `\left` and `\right`.

[image]

---

Just for information, as I said it *is* possible to use braces, but

1. it's deprecated
2. it's not really better input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Signop}{\mathsf{Sign}}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\parens}{(}{)}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Sign}{sO{}g}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
    {{\Signop}}% just the function name as ordinary symbol
    {\SignArg{#1}{#2}{#3}}% the more complex construction
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\SignArg}{mmm}{%
  \Signop % the operator
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% extensible delimiter
    \parens*{#3}%
   }
   {% sized delimiter
    \parens[#2]{#3}%
   }
}

\begin{document}

Ordinary: $a+\Sign+x$

\bigskip

With argument: $a+\Sign{b}+x$

\bigskip

With argument and size: $a+\Sign[\Big]{b}+x$

\bigskip

With extensible fences: $a+\Sign*{\dfrac{1}{2}}+x$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\futurelet` TeX primitive:

```
\def\Sign{\mathop{\mathsf{Sign}}\futurelet\next\SignA}
\def\SignA{\ifx \next\bgroup \expandafter\SignB \fi}
\def\SignB #1{\mathopen{}\left(#1\right)\mathclose{}}

%% test:
$\Sign X, \Sign{X+Y}$
```